# How does voltage splits when 2 devices was attached together

Tags: voltage

I'm new here and im not an electrical guy. Just trying to create some DIY stuff.

I want to know how to properly buy power adaptor for my newly purchased led light.

I have led light which is 12v and a 12v 2A power adaptor. This combination works OK so far.

Now I bought another led light and use the same power adaptor by commbining the positive and negative wire of the 2 LED lights which from my view works OK. No noticeable change in the light when powered ON

My question now

Does doing it this way divide the voltage that is being supplied to the led light to 2x6v or it is being supplied with 2x12v?

Is this the propper way of doing it or shall I need to buy another power adaptor per led light?

Thanks

Comment: both get 12V,  it sepends if the combind amps of the two strips can be provided by the power adaptor, if not you'll ge reduced brightness, blinking, or the adaptor will fail.

Comment: so it means Amp on the power adaptor is affected? if led light is both 2Amp each and power adaptor is 2Amp, the LED light will only get 1Amp each. is this correct?

Comment: Possibly correct, or one gets more than the other, or the adaptor breaks,

Comment: OK. That explains why my adaptor breaks and was too hot :) thanks. Will it hurt the led lights if i use 12v with high Amp rating. let say I am using 2 led lights now but will add 3 more in future. if i use adaptor with 12v 20Amp but will only use 2 led lights at the moment will it damage the led lights?

Comment: This being put on hold by  duskwuff, PeterJ, uint128_t, Peter Smith, placeholder rather than guidance being given for rewording , suggests that they design systems and then look for some sand, copper ore and hydrocarbons to start manufacturing their products from. (I'll not mention use of BLE ICs (let along modules), Mx processors, fabricating Broadcomm SOC equivalents,  electroforming their own Tantalum caps after sintering ... | In this case it is definitely a design question somewhat in disguise and can usefully be converted to a far more pure design question by minor modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name lights A & B. 
Do you have links or technical descriptions of A & B?

The following describes ways to determine if your power supply is overloaded.

Note that an overloaded power supply may work indefinitely, or fail quietly or burst into flames.

Presumably both are 12V rated.
They will also have a
Power (P) rating and a 
Current (I) rating.

Approximately P = V x I.
And I = P/V.

Va = voltage rating of A, IA = current rating of A etc.
It is essential that either:

- Va = Vb = Vpsu
  (Ia + Ib) <= Ipsu
  LEDs are operated in parallel from psu.
  ie connections are

  - V+_psu = V+_A = V+_B
  - V-_PSU = V-_A = V-_B

or

- A very special case
  (Va + VB) = Vpsu
  AND Ia = Ib <= Ipsu
  LEDs are run in series from psu.
  Connections are:

  - V+_psu = V+_A
  - V-_A = V+_B
  - V-_B = V-_psu
    This is unusual and best avoided.

**___________________________________**

**Test:**
As above: If Ia + Ib > Ipsu the psu is overloaded.

Operate A only from psu (power supply unit). Note brightness.
Operate B only from psu. Note brightness.
Operate A&B together from psu.
If brightness of A is lower than when by itself and/or brightness of B is lower than by itself then psu is overloaded.

If you have a DMM ()Digital Multimeter) - which is a really useful tool to have, then you can check as follows.

Set meter to 20 VDC or higher range.
Measure unloaded psu Vout = Voc
Voc probably 12V - 15V depending on psu.

Load with  A.
Measure Vo  = Vo_A
Vo_A probably 10V - 13V

Load with  B.
Measure Vo  = Vo_B
Vo_B probably 10V - 13V

Load with A & B. 
Measure Vo = Vo_AB
If Vab is well below Va or Vb and/or well below 12V then psu is overloaded.

Comment: thanks for the info but as I stated I am not an electrical guy. trying my best to understand the formula, it seems I need to have Psu with higher Amps. That explains why my Psu gave up last time I use the LED light together.

Comment: @Wayne You do not have to understand the formulae to benefit from what I said. If you simply carry out the 4 actions under "Test" starting "Operate A only ..." then it will tell you what you need to know. | AND if you provide " links or technical descriptions of A & B" as suggested we can probably help much more. Presumably you bought these from somewhere (strips and psu) - if you have web links you should give them.

Comment: it's unbranded led light I bought from chinatown like market. the only thing written on the LED light is GW-160w Made in China. PSU is also unbranded with output of 12v 2A. Im trying to google these items and will post back when I get any luck. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Wayne OK. Thanks. My  single paragraph test still applies.

Comment: But the problem is my PSU is already busted. the reason im asking is to not repeat the mistake. Looking at your explanation it looks like I have overloaded my PSU. Do you know how to get the Amp if watts and volts is given? Let say my Led Light is 12v and 160W. will you be able to tell what is the Amp? Thanks

Comment: @Wayne As per my answer above: Approximately P = V x I.
And I = P/V. So in this case I = P/V = 160/12 ~= 13.33 amps. That's and immense load for LED light strips if it's a real example. | 12V x @A = 24 Watts. 12V x 5A = 60 Watts etc .